# Loop through directory and rename files according to matching column value

Tags: r

I have a directory of files that I have already listed in my R environment with:

```
file_list <- list.files(path="C:/Users/$USER/Desktop/file_dir")

file_list = c("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt","file6.txt")
```

My metadata data frame has columns that identify the files with the correct corresponding names to each file.

```
df1$file = c("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5","file6") 

df1$real_name = c("pizza","burgers","wings","gushers","fruit_roll_ups","fried_chicken") 

df1:
file             real_name
file1              pizza
file2              burgers
file3              wings
file4              gushers
file5              fruit_roll_ups
file6              fried_chicken
```

My file list is actually much larger. I want to loop through the directory and match with the names in the file column so that I can rename the files with the real_name values. I have tried to use:

```
Meta <- df1$real_name
file_list <- file_list[order(match(basename(file_list), df1$real_name))]
file.rename(file_list, file.path(dirname(file_list), Meta))
```

But I am unsure how to append the .txt to match it or where else I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, a data.frame isn't even necessary here.

I'd use `file.rename()` which takes 2 vectors. The current file names and the new names.

```
file_list = c("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt","file6.txt") 

new_names <- c("pizza","burgers","wings","gushers","fruit_roll_ups","fried_chicken")

file.rename(file_list, paste0(new_names, ".txt")()
```

Comment: I think the point is that OP has some type of reference table that they want to join to the file names in order to lookup the new name.